# Deny from all folders except /index.php and two folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This is an odd configuration, I'll give you that, but I'm looking to deny access to all folders in our system but it must be able to access,

```
/index.php (Wordpress bootloader)
/wp-*/* (e.g. wp-content, wp-admin, etc.)
/templates/* (some of our templates and custom content)
```

Everything else is denied (and there are hundreds of folders).

The problem I have is allowing index.php and 2 folders and then denying everything else inside /.

I should be able to accept,

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/index.php
http://example.com/wp-content/...
http://example.com/wp-admin/...
http://example.com/wp-includes/...
http://example.com/templates/template.css
http://example.com/templates/subfolder/js/file.js
```

and reject,

```
http://example.com/thisIsAFolder
http://example.com/thisIsAnotherFolder
```

This is what I have,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    <Directory />
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>

    <Files index.php>
        Allow from all
    </Files>

    <Directory "/var/www(/|/wp*/|/templates/)">
        Allow from all

        Options FollowSymLinks

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

        RewriteRule ^ - [L]
        RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp/$2 [L]
        RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ wp/$2 [L]
        RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I continually receive `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Test Page` (using CentOS) and it allows for sub-directories because I allow `/`.

***EDIT***

This is the Apache config that ended up working for me. Big thanks to Jon Lin for the help.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    # first, deny all access
    <Directory />
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>

    # then start to allow access where required
    <Files index.php>
        Allow from all
    </Files>

    <Directory "/var/www/">
        Allow from all

        Options FollowSymLinks

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # go directly to index.php if it is accessed
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

        # re-write URL for wp-admin access
        RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

        # re-write wp-* access to route through wp/
        RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp/$2 [L]

        # re-write all .php files to route through wp/
        RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ wp/$2 [L]

        # go directly to real files and directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # respond to all other URLs by passing them through index.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . index.php [L]

        # deny access if URL doesn't start with these
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php)?$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-[^/]+/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/templates/
        RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-[^/]+/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/templates/
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

right before:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

The problem here though, is that permalinks will probably break, because a request like: `/posts/post-title/` will not match an of the "allowed" URI's. If that's a problem, then move it to right before this line:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: I ended up requiring a slight tweak but you put me in the right direction, no question. Thank you. Posting in an edit above.